# Passing a String into a Function With GDB

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

So, I have a function with the prototype according to GDB:

```
{std::string (std::string)} 0x56027729e545
     <function(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>
```

and I would like to pass a string into it using GDB. To attempt this, I've used the following GDB commands to create a new string on the heap.

```
set $mystr = (std::string*) malloc(sizeof(std::string))
call $mystr->basic_string()
call $mystr->assign("foobar")
call (std::string) function(*$mystr)
```

In the last line, I am getting the error

> ```
> Couldn't find method std::string::std::string.
> ```

Any ideas?

Unfortunately, I can't modify the code to fix this.

Comment: what is size of (std::string ) it is a class size is predefined iirc 0x20. the c_str() is either  pointer or ssoed plain string if len(c_str()) < 0x10   looks odd

Comment: @blabb Size is 0x20 / 32.